# Siempre da resultado correcto al comprobar contraseña y email, aunque el resultado sea incorrecto

Tags: java, poo, jdbc, sha1

estoy tratando de crear una clase que recoge la contraseña, la pasa a sha1 y comprueba si es correcta con la de la base de datos (en la BD esta guardada como sha1) y le indica al usuario si su contraseña es correcta, si no lo es, le indica que es incorrecta.

También estoy tratando de colocar el nombre de usuario y comprobar si existe en la bd, si existe el usuario es correcto, sino el usuario es incorrecto.
Por algún motivo no me hace las comprobaciones de la forma adecuada y siempre dice que el nombre y la contraseña son correctos.

Adjunto **clase passwordhelper:**

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;

public class PasswordHelper implements UserInterface {
    static Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

    String password;

    public PasswordHelper() {
    }

    public PasswordHelper(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getSha1(String password){

        return DigestUtils.sha1Hex(password);
    }

   public boolean isCorrectSha(String password, String sha){

        return (getSha1(password).equalsIgnoreCase(sha));
    }


    public String getUserName() {

        try {
            //se crea la conexion
            Connection conexion=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prueba", "root","");

            //crear objeto statement
            Statement miStatement = conexion.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

            //ejecutamos SQL
            ResultSet user = miStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM user");

                String email;
                System.out.println("Introduzca su email:");
                email = lector.nextLine();

                boolean existe = false;
                //recorrer  el resultSet
                while(user.next()) {

                if(email.equals(user.getString("email"))) {
                    //si la contraseña y el email existen marca como true la variable existe
                    existe = true;
                    //añadimos un break para que salga del bucle cuando encuentre la contraseña y el email
                    break;
                }
                }
                //verifica si la variable existe se encuentra en true
                if(existe=true) {
                    System.out.println("Nombre correcto");

                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("El usuario no existe");

                }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("no se puede conectar, el error es el siguiente:");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Acceso a BD correcto";
    }
}
```

**Clase Main:**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
        PasswordHelper user = new PasswordHelper();
        user.getUserName();

        try {
            //se crea la conexion
            Connection conexion=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prueba", "root","");

            //crear objeto statement
            Statement miStatement = conexion.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

            //ejecutamos SQL
            ResultSet user1 = miStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM user");

            //preguntar contraseña
            System.out.println("Introduce la contrasenya");
            String contraseña = lector.nextLine();

            PasswordHelper contra = new PasswordHelper(contraseña);

            contra.getSha1(contraseña);

            boolean existe = false;

            while(user1.next()) {

                if(contraseña.equals(user1.getString("password"))) {
                    //si la contraseña y el email existen marca como true la variable existe
                    existe = true;
                    //añadimos un break para que salga del bucle cuando encuentre la contraseña y el email
                    break;
                }
            }

            //verifica si la variable existe se encuentra en true

            if(existe=true) {
                System.out.println("Acceso correcto");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Resultado incorrecto");
            }       
            //cerramos la conexion
            user1.close();

        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("no se puede conectar, el error es el siguiente:");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Otro punto que e gustaría añadir es que no se si estoy implementando de forma adecuada la forma en la que actúa sha1 con el código.
Alguien me podría ayudar un poco? siento que voy dando palos de ciego sin saber muy bien como lo estoy haciendo. Gracias.

Comment: el resultado de getSha1() lo estás dejando perder, cambia eso y después nos actualizas porfa

Comment: como debería usarlo? no se muy bien como implementarlo para usarlo

Comment: no ignores el valor que regresa, si no es como si no lo hubieras llamado

Answer (score 0):

Esta funcion:

```
public String getSha1(String password){

    return DigestUtils.sha1Hex(password);
}
```

Devuelve algo, que vos no estas tomando en tu codigo.. Entonces que esperas hacer con el resultado?

Lo que vos le pasas a la funcion, no esta transformado, lo que esta transformado es la devolucion en esa funcion.

Y seguis cometiendo el mismo error en el SQL, de ir a buscar todos los registros en lugar del registro particular que necesitas.

Ojala nunca tengas 50000 usuarios ;)

Comment: Si tiene 50.000 usuarios o mas casi que RIP PC :c